# Multi-threads cause the runtime error in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

When I am trying to do multi-threads in Qt, for example:
If I create a class object in another class like this:

```
QThread thread;
Worker worker;
worker.moveToThread(thread);
```

it will cause the runtime error when I close the program.
But if I create the class object by pointer like this:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);
```

it will be no error. Why do I have to do like this?

And do I have to delete the pointer after using? If I do not, will that cause the memory leak? I see a lot of tutorials delete them like this:

```
connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL (finished()), worker, SLOT (deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (deleteLater()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt typically manages the memory of its objects. Lots of the documentation says this, but not all of it.

Your runtime error is caused by a double-delete. In the first example, when `worker` goes out of scope it will be destructed, and Qt will also attempt to `delete` it. In the second example, only Qt deletes it, and you do not.

If you look towards [Qt's own documentation of this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details), you can see them doing the same thing:

```
Controller() {
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
   ...
} // notice worker was not cleaned up here, which implies moveToThread takes ownership
```

However, [`moveToThread`'s documentation isn't clear on this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread).